# Transferring files through wifi network

Tags: wireless, files, router

I have a Desktop running windows 7 and a laptop running Ubuntu. I have a wireless N router connected to both. I wanted to transfer some files from my desktop to laptop. I found an option called "Browse Network" and i connected to my desktop from laptop. I started with file transfer. Now i have two doubts.

1. Does transferring files like this will consume bandwidth? Will it affect my internet usage allowance?
2. And the transfer speed is very slow. (Around 1.1 MB/sec). But my other downloads from internet are very fast. Y is this slow?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. > Does transferring files like this will consume bandwidth? Will it
   >   affect my internet usage allowance?

   - Bandwidth: It might, though it shouldn't be too much.
   - As for the usage allowance: No, it shouldn't. You aren't connecting to the internet, just passing files between computers on the local network. No connection to the outside involved, no getting of data from the outside world.
2. > And the transfer speed is very slow. (Around 1.1 MB/sec). But my other
   >   downloads from internet are very fast. Y is this slow?

   - Not exactly sure on this part. It might have to do with the connection that one of the systems has compared to the other. I'm guessing that the desktop is connected via Ethernet and the Laptop via WiFi? If it is, the speed issue might be because the data has to first go through the Ethernet to the Router, then be streamed to your Laptop. Beyond that, I can't honestly give any reason why this is happening.

Comment: But i didn't connect my desktop via Ethernet. I used a TP-Link TL-WN727N (150 Mbps) Usb adapter.